# recommend a unique jquery image streamer?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Im looking for a really nice jquery image streamer/slideshow plugin.

Something unobtrusive, that can take a group of images and fade through them and then update the list when done.

Something thats not basic, something that you can sit back and watch and incoming stream of uploaded photos.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it." Reference: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [nice list of jQuery Image Gallery/Slideshow Plugins along with Tutorials and Demos](http://speckyboy.com/2009/06/03/15-amazing-jquery-image-galleryslideshow-plugins-and-tutorials/).